# Loop through object javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, object

This is my response body. I want to select only Collaborator's "supportNotifications" key-value set to true, how can I do that?

```
{
  "status": true,
  "date": "2022-04-06T16:33:13.630Z",
  "data": {
    "collaborators": [
      {
        "name": "Paul",
        "lastCheckin": "2022-03-31T19:54:50.584Z",
        "sales": 1,
        "createdAt": "2022-03-30T14:47:48.478Z",
        "id": "62446d4ab7f4da001e8f40dc",
        "supportNotification": true,
        "collaboratorId": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "John",
        "lastCheckin": null,
        "sales": 0,
        "createdAt": "2022-03-01",
        "id": "62446ea4b7f4da001e8f40df",
        "supportNotification": false,
        "collaboratorId": 6
      }
    ],
    "count": 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let response = {
  "status": true,
  "date": "2022-04-06T16:33:13.630Z",
  "data": {
    "collaborators": [
      {
        "name": "Paul",
        "lastCheckin": "2022-03-31T19:54:50.584Z",
        "sales": 1,
        "createdAt": "2022-03-30T14:47:48.478Z",
        "id": "62446d4ab7f4da001e8f40dc",
        "supportNotification": true,
        "collaboratorId": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "John",
        "lastCheckin": null,
        "sales": 0,
        "createdAt": "2022-03-01",
        "id": "62446ea4b7f4da001e8f40df",
        "supportNotification": false,
        "collaboratorId": 6
      }
    ],
    "count": 2
  }
};

const collaborators = response.data.collaborators.filter(c => c.supportNotification);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you each collaborator object that has supportNotification = true. Is this the result you are trying to select?

```
var body = {
  status: true,
  date: "2022-04-06T16:33:13.630Z",
  data: {
    collaborators: [
      {
        name: "Paul",
        lastCheckin: "2022-03-31T19:54:50.584Z",
        sales: 1,
        createdAt: "2022-03-30T14:47:48.478Z",
        id: "62446d4ab7f4da001e8f40dc",
        supportNotification: true,
        collaboratorId: 1,
      },
      {
        name: "John",
        lastCheckin: null,
        sales: 0,
        createdAt: "2022-03-01",
        id: "62446ea4b7f4da001e8f40df",
        supportNotification: false,
        collaboratorId: 6,
      },
    ],
    count: 2,
  },
};

var result = [];

body.data.collaborators.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.supportNotification === true) {
    result.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```